# ¿Cómo detectar si un proceso lanzado desde otra aplicación se está ejecutando?

Tags: c#, .net, proceso, aplicación-escritorio

Tengo una aplicación que lanza varios procesos. El objetivo de esta aplicación es monitorear si se están ejecutando una vez lanzados y si no, entonces matar el proceso si éste no responde o volverlo a lanzar si no se está ejecutando. Recorriendo cada uno de los procesos que la aplicación sabe que lanzó inicialmente y verificando si se están ejecutando mediante la función `ObtenerProceso` (tengo los PID de cada proceso cuando fueron lanzados pero eso no me asegura que el proceso haya muerto y otro proceso tomó el mismo PID).

```
public static Process ObtenerProceso(int pid, string ubicacion, string argumentos = "", string dominio = "", string usuario = "")
{
    Process proceso = null;
    Process procesoAux = null;

    if (Process.GetProcesses().Any(x => x.Id == pid))
    {
        procesoAux = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        if (procesoAux.MainModule.FileName.ToUpper() == ubicacion.ToUpper())
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"select * from Win32_Process where ProcessId = {procesoAux.Id}");
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                if (mo["CommandLine"] != null && mo["CommandLine"].ToString().ToUpper().Replace($"\"{ubicacion.ToUpper()}\"", string.Empty).Trim() == argumentos.ToUpper().Trim())
                {
                    if (dominio.Trim() != string.Empty && usuario.Trim() != string.Empty)
                    {
                        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
                        int respuesta = Convert.ToInt32(mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
                        if (respuesta == 0 && $"{argList[1]}\\{argList[0]}".ToUpper() == $"{dominio}\\{usuario}".ToUpper())
                            proceso = procesoAux;
                    }
                    else
                        proceso = procesoAux;
                }
        }

    }

    return proceso;
}
```

La función retorna un `null` en caso de no encontrar el proceso.

Este método me ha funcionado bien, el problema es que es un poco demorado para la cantidad de procesos que debo monitorear. Los consumos más altos de tiempo han sido en la instrucción `select` que obtiene información más detallada del proceso como el usuario que ejecutó el proceso y la línea de comando que se le envió al ejecutable.

¿Existe algún método más efectivo para realizar esta acción?

Aclaración adicional

De un mismo ejecutable la aplicación debe lanzar varias instancias (pero con distintos argumentos de iniciación), por lo que capturar el proceso por nombre no es recomendable, en esos casos solo los diferenciaría mediante la línea de comandos con la que se ejecutó el proceso. Adicionalmente reviso si el proceso responde mediante dos criterios, primero con la propiedad `Process.Responding` y segundo cada proceso lanzado actualiza cada cierto tiempo una base de datos SQLite la cual mi aplicación consulta para saber cuándo fue el último reporte del proceso y saber si no está "bloqueado". Dejo la clase `Aplicacion` que representa un proceso que voy a lanzar y monitorear.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;

namespace Yggdrasil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Representa una Aplicación a monitorear.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Aplicacion
    {
        #region Definición de variables privadas.
        private int id;
        private int idMaquina;
        private int pid = -999999999;
        private string nombre;
        private string descripcion;
        private string ubicacion;
        private string argumentos;
        private string dominio;
        private string usuario;
        private SecureString clave;
        private bool activa;
        private DateTime fechaCreacion;
        #endregion

        #region Propiedades.
        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la identificación de la Aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la identificación del proceso de la Aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public int PID
        {
            get
            {
                return pid;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la identificación de la Máquina donde se ejecuta la Aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public int IdMaquina
        {
            get
            {
                return idMaquina;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene el nombre de la Aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public string Nombre
        {
            get
            {
                return nombre;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la descripción de la Aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public string Descripcion
        {
            get
            {
                return descripcion;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la ubicación del ejecutable de la Aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public string Ubicacion
        {
            get
            {
                return ubicacion;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene los argumentos de inicio de la aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public string Argumentos
        {
            get
            {
                return argumentos;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determina si la Aplicación está activa o inactiva. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Activa
        {
            get
            {
                return activa;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene el usuario con el que se ejecuta la aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public string Usuario
        {
            get
            {
                return usuario;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene el dominio en el que se ejecuta la aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public string Dominio
        {
            get
            {
                return dominio;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la contraseña del usuario con el que se ejecuta la aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public SecureString Clave
        {
            get
            {
                return clave;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la última fecha en la que la aplicación respondió. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FechaResponde
        {
            get
            {
                return ObtenerUltimoRespondeProceso();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la última fecha en la que la aplicación reportó actividad. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FechaReporte
        {
            get
            {
                return ObtenerUltimoReporteProceso();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la fecha de creación del registro de la aplicación. Esta propiedad no se puede establecer.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FechaCreacion
        {
            get
            {
                return fechaCreacion;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region implementación de constructores.
        /// <summary>
        /// Inicializa un objeto de la clase Aplicacion.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identificación de la aplicación.</param>
        public Aplicacion(int id)
        {
            Inicializar(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inicializa un objeto de la clase Aplicacion.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identificación de la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="idMaquina">Identificación de la Máquina en donde se ejecuta la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="nombre">Nombre de la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="descripcion">Descripción de la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="ubicacion">Ubicación del ejecutable de la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="argumentos">Argumentos con los que se ejecuta la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="dominio">Dominio del usuario de la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="usuario">Usuario con el que se ejecuta la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="clave">Contraseña del usuario con el que se ejecuta la aplicación.</param>
        /// <param name="activa">Indica si la aplicación está activa o inactiva.</param>
        /// <param name="fechaCreacion">Fecha de creación del registro de la aplicación.</param>
        public Aplicacion(int id, int idMaquina, string nombre, string descripcion, string ubicacion, string argumentos, string dominio, string usuario, string clave, int pid, bool activa, DateTime fechaCreacion)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.idMaquina = idMaquina;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
            this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
            this.argumentos = argumentos;
            this.activa = activa;
            this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
            this.dominio = dominio;
            this.usuario = usuario.ToUpper();
            this.clave = Utilidades.String2SecureString(clave);
            this.pid = pid;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Implementación de métodos privados.
        /// <summary>
        /// Inicializa un objeto de la clase Aplicación conociendo su identificación.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identificación de la Aplicación.</param>
        private void Inicializar(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    DataTable dtAplicacion = controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT * FROM aplicacion WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
                    foreach (DataRow drAplicacion in dtAplicacion.Rows)
                    {
                        this.id = id;
                        idMaquina = Convert.ToInt32(drAplicacion["id_maquina"]);
                        nombre = drAplicacion["nombre_aplicacion"].ToString();
                        descripcion = drAplicacion["descripcion"].ToString();
                        ubicacion = drAplicacion["ubicacion"].ToString();
                        argumentos = drAplicacion["argumentos"].ToString();
                        dominio = drAplicacion["dominio"].ToString();
                        usuario = drAplicacion["usuario"].ToString().ToUpper();
                        clave = Utilidades.String2SecureString(drAplicacion["clave"].ToString());
                        if (drAplicacion["activa"].ToString() == "S")
                            activa = true;
                        else
                            activa = false;
                        pid = Convert.ToInt32(drAplicacion["pid"]);
                        fechaCreacion = (DateTime)drAplicacion["fecha_creacion"];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al inicializar un objeto Aplicacion. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Actualiza el PID de la Aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pid">Nueva identificación del proceso para la Aplicación.</param>
        private void ActualizarPID(int pid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET pid = {pid} WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
                    this.pid = pid;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar actualizar el PID. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la fecha del último reporte del proceso.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private DateTime ObtenerUltimoReporteProceso()
        {
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
            Process proceso = ObtenerProcesoActual();

            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad FROM reporte_proceso WHERE id_proceso = {proceso.Id} AND UPPER(ubicacion) = '{ubicacion.ToUpper()}'").Rows[0]["cantidad"]);
                    if (cantidad > 0)
                    {
                        if (cantidad > 1000)
                            controladorBD.Ejecutar($"DELETE FROM reporte_proceso WHERE id_proceso = {proceso.Id} AND UPPER(ubicacion) = '{ubicacion.ToUpper()}'");

                        fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', DATETIME(x.fecha)) AS fecha FROM (SELECT MAX(fecha_creacion) AS fecha FROM reporte_proceso WHERE id_proceso = {proceso.Id} AND UPPER(ubicacion) = '{ubicacion.ToUpper()}') x").Rows[0]["fecha"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar obtener la fecha del último reporte de una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }

            return fecha;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la fecha de la última vez que respondió la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private DateTime ObtenerUltimoRespondeProceso()
        {
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    object obj_fecha = controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', DATETIME(fecha_responde)) AS fecha FROM aplicacion WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}").Rows[0]["fecha"];
                    if (obj_fecha != null)
                        fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(obj_fecha), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar obtener la última fecha de respuesta de una aplicación {ex.Message}");
            }

            return fecha;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene el proceso actual de la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Process ObtenerProcesoActual()
        {
            return Utilidades.ObtenerProceso(pid, ubicacion, argumentos, dominio, usuario);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Implementación de métodos públicos
        /// <summary>
        /// Inactiva el proceso.
        /// </summary>
        public void Inactivar()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET activa = 'N' WHERE id_aplicacion = {id} AND activa = 'S'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar inactivar una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Activa el proceso.
        /// </summary>
        public void Activar()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET activa = 'S' WHERE id_aplicacion = {id} AND activa = 'N'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar activar una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Actualiza la última fecha en la que la aplicación respondió.
        /// </summary>
        public void ActualizarRespuesta()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET fecha_responde = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar actualizar la fecha de respuesta de una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Elimina la aplicación de la configuración.
        /// </summary>
        public void Eliminar()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"DELETE FROM aplicacion WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar eliminar una aplicaión. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Verifica si la aplicación está en ejecución.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool EnEjecucion()
        {
            return ObtenerProcesoActual() != null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determina si la aplicación está respondiendo.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool EstaRespondiendo()
        {
            return ObtenerProcesoActual().Responding;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ejecuta la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        public void Ejecutar()
        {
            Process proceso = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = ubicacion,
                    ErrorDialog = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(ubicacion),
                    Arguments = argumentos,
                    Domain = dominio,
                    UserName = usuario,
                    Password = clave
                }
            };

            proceso.Start();
            ActualizarPID(proceso.Id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Mata el proceso actual de la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        public void Matar()
        {
            ObtenerProcesoActual().Kill();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias intentar ejecutando en paralelo la validacion mediante `Parallel.ForEach(mos.Cast<ManagementObject>(),
                (mo, loopState) =>
{
    //proceso
});`, debes hacer primero el `Cast` ya que se te podría generar un boqueo si lo tomas directamente del `Get`

Comment: Podrías hacer que tus programas cada X tiempo escriban en un fichero la hora en el momento de la modificación de ese archivo para poder tener así constancia de que ese proceso se sigue ejecutando.
Ahora sabiendo que tus procesos si no están muertos cada X tiempo modifican un archivo concreto con la fecha de última modificación, solo tendrás que crearte un programa que mire cada fichero que escribe tus procesos y comprobar la diferencia de la fecha y hora actual a la fecha y hora del fichero. Sabiendo así si tu proceso sigue "vivo"o "muerto"

Answer (score 2):

Si sabes el nombre de los procesos que tienes que controlar, una manera sencilla es con esto:

```
Process[] LocalByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("Nombre_del_proceso");
```

Si LocalByName no tiene elementos es que el proceso no está en funcionamiento, si tiene algún elemento quiere decir que el proceso está funcionando.

La clase Process tiene otros métodos que te pueden interesar como obtener el proceso a través del id.